# Submit value of a TextBox without reloading page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reload, tic-tac-toe

I'm working on an ASP.NET based TicTacToe game. The problem I have with it is that:
The game is played between two users. When the first one types 'x' in the TextBox I want the 'x' to be shown on the second player's computer without reloading the page. 
I don't know if some code will help but here is the way I did it without reloading(the user must reload the page manually... dumb):

```
protected void TopLeft_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Lock();
        GameBoard gameBoard = new GameBoard();
        gameBoard.board[0, 0] = char.Parse(this.TopLeft.Text);
        Application["TopLeft"] = gameBoard.board[0, 0];
        Application.UnLock();
    }
```

And then, on page pre render:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        Application.Lock();
        if(Application["TopLeft"] != "0")
        {
            this.TopLeft.Text = Application["TopLeft"].ToString();
        }
        ...
```

And so on...
I'd be very thankfull to anyone who can help!

Comment: You'll want to read up on AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking about [Partial Page Update](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax).

First, you need to place the client `TextBox` or what ever other controls that you need to reload inside an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx).

Then, you need to call the [UpdatePanel.Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update.aspx) to update those controls whenever you need.

Comment: @Tsvetan: UpdatePanel.Update() reload just the updated values of its contents on the same page. If it has been called on one peer, then it will update the contents on this peer's page.

Comment: @Tsvetan: An example from stack overflow is voting. When you vote a question, then new value is the total voting that happened till the indicator is refreshed. But the indicator wont be refreshed by itself.

Comment: @Tsvetan: But of course you can update it intervaly using a timer for example.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to do this.  I recommend looking at some of the AJAX capabilities that jQuery offers but you can also look at the AJAX Toolkit from Microsoft.

Here is documentation for AJAX in jQuery:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

I feel this is much "lighter" than what Microsoft offers out of the box.  You can find out more about the Microsoft AJAX toolkit here:

- http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/

Comment: Thanks! But I don't have so much time reading docs, so, is there a way to reload the page of the user who is waiting after the input of the player who was on turn?

Answer (score 1):

Check out AJAX. This will require client scripting to submit and detect updates without submitting or updating the entire page.

Note, however, that this is a fairly advanced topic and will not simply be a little snippet of code you can add. I would recommend a good AJAX/JavaScript/jQuery book.